# Node Express CRUD application folder structure

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, crud, directory-structure

I am using the following folder structure for my express CRUD application. I use it to have ideal manageable code of each file containing not more than 70 lines of code. What are your thoughts on the folder structure?

```
.
├── bin\
│   └── www
├── common\
│   ├── enums\
│   │   └── logTypesEnum.js
│   └── validators\
│       └── studentNameValidator.js
├── config\
│   └── db.js # config file for database connection
├── models\
│   └── log.js # contains model data for model 'log'
├── routes\
│   ├── log\
│   │   ├── index.js # handles all routes for /log/ endpoints and requires files in the directory and also contains middleware code
│   │   ├── insert.js # handles all routes for /log/insert endpoints
│   │   ├── remove # handles all routes for /log/remove endpoints
│   │   └── exportCSV.js # handles all routes for /log/exportCSV endpoints
│   └── student\
│       ├── index.js 
│       ├── insert.js
│       └── remove.js
├── public\
│   ├── javascripts
│   ├── images
│   └── stylesheets
├── views\
│   ├── log\
│   │   ├── index.jade
│   │   ├── insert.jade
│   │   ├── remove.jade
│   │   ├── exportCSV.jade
│   └── student\
│       ├── index.jade
│       └── insert.jade
└── app.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you decided on the number 70 unless you read somewhere that 70 makes some sort of ideal microservice which your structure does not allow for anyways.

As to the directory structure. I have come to the conclusion that internal directory structures are usually based on the programmer or team leader. It is more of a matter of what makes sense in your head as you see the visual design and implementation of your code.

That said, IMHO, overly complicated or let us say overly structured directory structures in Node and say for instance PHP cause an inordinate amount of moving up and down directory trees in order to access code, classes or just plain functions. Not to mention that it becomes jibberish for those who may come after you to maintain the code.

So use the directory structure you feel at home with. But make it clean and not complicated. Do not try to pigeonhole every aspect of every call and function into a specific 70 line definable directory structure. (again no clue where that number came from).

Clean, simple and sensible. 
Those would be the best rules to follow IMHO.

Edit based on OP questions below:

1. Clarity of code is not defined by the amount of lines. When I test coders, no matter what language they specialize in, put some code up on the screen and ask them to translate that code line for line into plain English. First this actually tests the candidate ability. And second if the code is clear and good, then any other coder  should be able to read it and clearly understand what is going on in the code. (Actually it tests both the original coder and the candidate.) 
   So clear code is not about lines. It is about excellent coding practices and the ability to make your code do what you envision.
2. Microservices has become sort of a buzzword. But essentially it simply means "focused". It means that you are creating a module to do a specific task So each module in your system does a specific task or tasks essential to your system and only focuses on that task. I think that may be actually what you are striving for. There are quite a few really good articles out there on Node and Microservices.

Comment: By 70 I meant to scroll down not more than twice, just for the sake of maintaining the code clarity. Could you please comment further on the line `ideal microservice which your structure does not allow for anyways`. Pointing out the specific fallback of this structure would be really helpful. and @twg thanks for your response.

Comment: I edited my answer to address your question. Hope that helps